# eclipseでpayara serverにjsfを使った動的プロジェクトのdeploy時にエラーが発生する

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

eclipseでpayara serverにjsfを使ったexample2という動的プロジェクトのdeploy時にエラーが発生してしまいます。

このエラーをなくし、この動的プロジェクトをserverにdeployしたい。

**開発環境**
java 1.8
payara server 5
jsf 2.2
動的プロジェクト 4.0

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
deploy is example2 failing=error occurred during deployment: exception while loading the app : java.lang.illegalstateexception: containerbase.addchild: start: org.apache.catalina.lifecycleexception: java.lang.runtimeexception: javax.faces.facesexception: unable to find cdi beanmanager. please see server.log for more details.
```

#### 試したこと

- jsf のversionを下げる
- 動的プロジェクトのversionを下げる

Comment: 情報が不十分であるため、他者は問題が発生する環境を再現できないように思われます(どのような内容のファイルが有って、それらがどう構成されているのかという情報が必要です)。 / エラーメッセージには `server.log` に詳細が書かれているとありますが、どのような情報が出力されているでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。unable to find cdi beanmanagerがserver.logにはありました。beanマネージャーが何なのかを明かしていこうと思います。

Answer (score 0):

以下の組み合わせだと私はエラーが起きませんでした。お試し下さい。
・プロジェクト・ファセットでのJSF:v2.2
・動的Webモジュールバージョン:v3.1

ちなみに他の環境は以下です。
・EclipseはPleiadesから2022-06を使用
・Payara Server Community v5.2022.2
・JDKはAmazon Corretto jdk1.8.0_332（jdk11.0.15_9でも動作することは確認しました。)

以上、宜しくお願い致します。